# Why does putting a string in a struct cause a crash?

Tags: c++, string, struct

I have a structure that contains, among other things, a couple of strings.

```
struct item {
    string item_name;
    int item_property_1;
    double item_property_2;
}
```

Later I initialize them:

```
item item1;
item1.item_name = "Name of Item";
item1.item_property_1 = 5;
item1.item_property_2 = 10.0;
```

If I comment out the line assigning the string, it runs fine.  With the string assignment, it crashes.  I have no idea why.

I have now commented out the contents of every other function trying to track down what could be causing the suggested corruption, and it still crashes.  I'm down to one struct with a few strings and numbers, and if I assign a value to any of the strings it crashes.

What could cause that corruption?

*edit* Adding in, by request, the smallest amount of real code that causes a crash.  Commented out sections are omitted.

```
struct player_c {
        string advClass;
        int role;
};

player_c shadow;

Shadow::Shadow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Shadow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    shadow.advClass = " ";
    shadow.role = 1;
}
```

That's all that's left.  I only included the int to test and verify that assigning it a value worked fine, and so long as the string is commented out it does.  Any use of strings in the struct causes a crash.

I don't NEED them there.  I'm not currently using those strings, I put them in the struct because I intend to use them later, but I can accomplish the same purpose without them.  Right now I just want to understand why.

Comment: You have no compile time errors and the program crashes at run time?

Comment: the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Probably the crash is **not** caused by that line, something else in your code wrote garbage on the _item1_ memory location.

Comment: Can you post the smallest amount of code that reproduces the crash?

Comment: I have a similar problem, seems `string` is uninitialized https://gist.github.com/2639351

Answer (score 2):

That code is perfectly legal. The error is in some of the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2):

The code runs fine: http://ideone.com/1NoMG

There must be something wrong elsewhere in the code, or your compiler.

Also, `item1.item_name` is initialized when you create `item1`. `item1.item_name = "Name of Item";` is an assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks ok but you might have memory corruption elsewhere in your code.

Comment: What could cause that memory corruption?  I have literally everything else commented out right now except for the struct declaration and the one line to set the string value, and it crashes every time.  If I assign one of the numbers, it works fine.  The only problem is with strings.

Comment: Does it crash if you leave only `item item1;`? This will create string member and initialize it to an empty string. This allocates memory so I would expected event this to crash. Try to assign it with some other (shorter) literal or move this code around (the best at the very beginning of `main()`). Try to change the order of struct members - put integer and double before string and see what happens.

Comment: I put the strings at beginning of the struct and then tried again at the end. Both crashed.  I tried moving the assignment to another function, but as soon as that was called the program crashed.

Comment: What happens if you try to assign (some) independent string object (without using struct)? Can you use debugger and see what's happening in `std::string`?

Comment: I don't have a debugger, but declaring string test_str and then setting test_str = "test"; works just fine, both when it is declared locally and then tried again as a global variable like the struct is.

Comment: @BojanKomazec An empty string need not allocate memory, that will depend on the implementation, and I would expect the library not to allocate until needed.

Comment: As @juanchopanza asked in his comment, can you please put here the minimal code that compiles and reproduces the problem? You mentioned that struct is a global variable. Have you tried to initialize it outside any function, through list of initializers? (I hope you are aware of all dangers of using globals...you should avoid them).

Comment: @David I agree. And just found related question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072678/default-capacity-of-stdstring

Comment: I updated the original question with the minimal code that crashes.

Comment: @RuQu `Shadow` constructor, `QMainWindow(QWidget*)`, `Ui::Shadow` constructor or `Ui::Shadow::setupUi` are all possible suspects for causing memory corruption. Can you please post their definitions as well? Have you tried to move initializer list assignments into the body of the `Shadow` c-tor, after struct members assignments?

Comment: Well, I don't understand the original cause, but simply replacing the struct by writing a new class with all of the struct's contents set as public by default gives me the exact same functionality and none of this problem.  Wish I understood where the problem was coming from though.

Answer (score 2):

The following compiles and runs as expected with G++ version 4.6.1 without any crash. You must have something else incorrect.

```
[21:18:32] user@host:[~]$ cat t.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct item {
        string name;
        int number;
};

int main()
{
        item i;
        i.name = "blah";
        i.number = 12;

        cout << "name=" << i.name << " number=" << i.number;
}


[21:18:34] user@host:[~]$ ./a.out 
name=blah number=12

[21:18:36] user@host:[~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have by any chance a global variable of type Shadow? Maybe shadow global variable is not initialized when another global is constructed.