# What exactly happens if I assign a value to a string position that is not used at the moment?

Tags: c++, string

I almost never use the c++ string type but I'll need to use a set of strings so I think they would be the best way to go...

I coded like this:

```
string a;
a[0] = 'b';
printf("%s", a.c_str());
```

and it printed the letter 'b'

but when I tried:

```
string a;
// i bellow would be a number from 0 to 9, so I add 48 to get the correspondent char
a[0] = 48 + i; 
printf("%s", a.c_str());
```

It is not printing a single digit...

My question is: did it print 'b' correctly in the first case just because of a lucky undefined behavior?

I'm asking that because if I already had something in position 0, the assignment a[0] = 48 + i; would print the number correctly.

Comment: That would be *undefined behavior*. Use `.at()` rather than `operator[]` and not even the first one will succeed (loose term, since even with `operator[]` its "success" was a figment). The moment you indexed through `operator[]` to an invalid position the slow-train to parts-unknown left the station.

Comment: _'My question is: did it print 'b' correctly in the first case just because of a lucky undefined behavior?'_ Yes I'm afraid so :/ ...

Comment: Hum, ok.. thanks =) I asked because in cpluplus.com doesn't say what would happen if access beyond the current string limit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String is a dynamic array so you cant call to undefined part of memory. The calling 
`string a;
a[0] = 'b';
printf("%s", a.c_str());`

Is very dangerous because u already access to other part of memory and overwrote this. I guess your program will throw an error in other part of program. Look what u did: 
`string a; a[0] = 'b'; printf("%d ", a.size());` output will be of course `0`. 
You have to reserve memory before that like: `a.resize(10)`

Comment: oh, good catch, I hadn't tried displaying the length, it is showing 0 here also.. I initialized the string with some garbage that had the length I would need

Comment: If u want adding chars in order u can use a.push_back(char) this function automatically allocates memory and if it is end function reallocate twice length of, because with every reallocate (resize) string is copying and twice allocate entail effective complexity O(2n) copies

Comment: a.size() tries to give you the 'string length'. In your case string a has letter 'b' in index 0, but rest of (to some platform dependent length) the characters of inside array is gibberish. When function size() tries to find out null char, it may or may not finds it and consequently, you may or may not get your length. It's undefined.

Comment: @SargiEran: `size()` doesn't "try to find null char". The `size()` member function has constant time complexity and no conforming implementation does a scan to find the string length. The length is either stored in the string object or computed by pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Please correct me if I am wrong, in C++11 it is O(1) and C++98 it is undefined. So, from my point of view we can't exactly say string size() has constant time, since we have far outweighed number of people with C++98.

Comment: @SargiEran: I will defer to you since I can't find a copy of the old standard.

Answer (score -1):

Please correct me anyone, if this is a platform dependent answer. I used VS2012 and had no time to test with gcc.

Once you creates a string like,
    string s;

It allocates some initial memory. You can see it by,

```
s.capacity();//For me it gets 15
```

It returns some non-zero value (again in VS2012). So, having,

```
s[0] = 'b';
```

is meaningful.

If you try something,

```
a[10000] = 'b';
```

It'll crash your program.

The case for a[0] = 48 + i ( 0 <= i <= 9), I'd say this shouldn't be a problem other than it prints some gibberish after your single digit.

Comment: `s[0] = 'b';` is not meaningful. It is the string `size()`, not the `capacity()`, that determines what the valid indices are.

Comment: re "prints some gibberish", that's because the assignment obliterates the zero-byte that the string implementation assumes is there. so, the output operation is accessing memory possibly beyond the buffer size. this is also UB, and can cause a crash.

Comment: It is platform dependent. I checked with gcc which allocates 0 and VS2012 allocates 15 bytes. C++ standards do not specify it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072678/default-capacity-of-stdstring

Comment: Assigning to `s[i]` where `i >= s.size()` is undefined behavior regardless of the capacity.

Comment: Hum... so it won't crash if you are inside the capacity... from the example I tried I think that if you are within the capacity it will store the char but will only print the first LEN chars... It might be platform dependent but try the following: reserver some 5 in capacity, do s[2] = 'a'; s[0] = 'a'; s1[1] = 'a'; and print after each assignment to see if you get the same behavior, on mine it printed 3 a's after the third assignment