# Constructing strings for appending

Tags: c++, c++11

I have to construct a string by concatenating a few other strings. I also know the maximum size of the string, and I want to reserve the capacity so there are no reallocations. My code right now looks something like this:

```
#include <string>
using std::string;

// Setup
...

string a,b,c;

// Strings are filled with relevant data
...

string msg;
msg.reserve(200);
msg = "A=";  msg += a; msg += ',';
msg += "B="; msg += b; msg += ',';
msg += "C="; msg += c; msg += '.';
```

I previously used `stringstream` for this, but performance was twice as slow.
Is there a way to reserve the string capacity at construction, instead of having to allocate memory twice? Also is there a better (faster) way of appending the strings?

Comment: This code won't allocate twice. The default constructor doesn't allocate any memory.

Comment: @SebastianRedl The object itself must live somewhere in memory. I thought that the memory for the actual string is contiguous with the memory of the object if it was possible to reserve at construction

Comment: @EyalK. I don't see anything like that in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

Comment: @SebastianRedl `std::string` tends to allocate some memory even for default construction. https://wandbox.org/permlink/n7uQ4kdra2KW6G4P

Comment: @EyalK. : in your example the objects have automatic storage and common implementation will use the stack for them, while the actual string memory has dynamic storage and common implementations put them into the heap. So having the memory for the actual string contiguous with the memory of the object is quite uncommon...

Comment: @songyuanyao: that's probably SSO.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Even without SSO, since C++11 `operator[size()]` must return a valid reference to null char, so I think `std::string` has to do something for this. Yes it might not be a dynamic allocation.

Comment: @songyuanyao: A simple `if` statement and a `char` member can solve that (not that this would be the optimal implementation!)

Comment: @songyuanyao The reference to the pseudo-nul is also solved by SSO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to reserve the string capacity at construction instead of having to allocate memory twice?

There is no "allocating memory twice" here. You correctly create a string then ask it to reserve some memory. Other than reserving a more accurate amount (rather than just guessing `200`), you're fine.

Technically, [an implementation *is* allowed to start off with an unspecified capacity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9072702/560648), but it's likely that you're seeing the results of small-string optimisation (a statically-allocated buffer inside the `std::string` itself, to avoid dynamic allocations in some cases) rather than this feature being used.

If you're really concerned about it, you could instantiate the string with 200 `\0` characters, then erase them all; then its underlying capacity will be consistent.

Comment: Alright, thanks. What about the way I'm constructing the string? I feel like there must be some more efficient way to do it (I need to push out these messages as fast as possible)

Comment: @EyalK.: Don't worry about it. Finish your program then benchmark this function and see whether you need to improve it. But you probably don't.

Comment: This function is not in a tight loop, but it does participate in a sort of "race" against rival messages. It will not show up in profiling, but it does need to be as fast as possible to win the race

Comment: @EyalK. then redesign your program so you don't have a data race?

Comment: @Caleth The race is between my program and rival programs, not a data race in the multithreading sense

Comment: @EyalK.: It is likely that this has no observable affect on the results of the race. It's very very very fast, much faster than network I/O functions. _Profile_ before you spend more time micro-optimising.

Comment: Are you sure that erasing the whole content will leave the capacity untouched? AFAIK this is not specified by standard. `clear` has the effect of `erase`, and I could not find any guarantee for capacity in `erase`.

Comment: You don't need to erase all the nuls in one go, you could fill with msg.replace

Comment: @SergeBallesta: It seems I was thinking of `std::vector`

Comment: @Caleth: It would only be a `mySize = 0` operation; no actual bytes are harmed in the making of this solution (though see above where Serge points out this may not actually be true for strings)